# how save my spinner item

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

i am using spinner and my spinner is working good but item of spinner not saving for example when i choose  font2 for my text my texts font is change and my change is saved for next but in spinner show font1 after close my program
my code is :
in this code i add item to spinner

```
package com.testfont.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener; 
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class font extends Activity {
public static String font="tahoma.ttf";

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.font);
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String item1 = "font1";
        String item2 = "font2";
        //String item3 = "فونت سه";


        list.add(item1);
        list.add(item2);
        //list.add(item3);


        Arrayadapt ad = new Arrayadapt(getApplicationContext(), 0, list);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp.setAdapter(ad);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItemView,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //boolean selected = false;
                if(position == 0){
                    font="tahoma.ttf";
                }else if(position == 1){
                    font="QuranTaha.ttf";
                }               
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

}   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

public String getFont() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return font;
}
}
```

in this code i addapt to spinner

```
package com.testfont.test;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Arrayadapt extends ArrayAdapter{


Typeface tf;
List<String> _list;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public Arrayadapt(Context _context, int _resource,
            List<String> _items) {
        super(_context, _resource, _items);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = _context;
        this.tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),"font/Yekan.ttf");
        this._list = _items;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = mInflater;
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tspinner, parent,
                false);
        TextView v = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        v.setTypeface(tf);
        v.setText(Farsi.Convert(_list.get(position)));
        return row;
    }


    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = mInflater;
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tspinner, parent,
                false);
        TextView v = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        v.setTypeface(tf);
        v.setText(Farsi.Convert(_list.get(position)));
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a). If your items in spinner is static. You can use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

For example, you can save spinner position in onPause function and load spinner position in onResume function.

b). If your items is dinamic. You can use sqlite for storing items and spinner position.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html